# It is possible to have sign in with user and credentials(JWT) and Oauth2 sign in with google?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am developing an app, now in this app I have developed login with **JWT**, and now I want to do a login with **google**, I have read about **oauth2** but I dont't find any tutorial which implements oauth2 and jwt common login.
In **springSecurity** i have this configuration

```
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailService);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()));
        http.addFilter(new JWTValidationToken(authenticationManager()));
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
```

To generate and validation token, but if I use oauth2 I don't have token to validate it, then my token filters will send error. A lot of pages has in their registration page the log in with google and i know is possible but I do not know how to do it.

Thanks for your time and sorry for my engish, is not my native languaje

Comment: Do like this https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt

Comment: Hi @ArthurKlezovich, i have read the post, but in that post exaplains how create a jwt authentication, but not a jwt and oauth2 authentication.

Comment: See [JWT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) in the reference docs to avoid using a custom filter. Use both [OAuth 2.0 Login](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/login) and [JWT Login](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) samples as a reference point.

Comment: Hi @SteveRiesenberg, to use JWT is neccesary custom and create several filters to create and validate token

Comment: Why have you written a custom jwtfilter? Spring security has full support for jwt and already has a built in jwtfilter. Writing custom security is bad practice. Please read the spring security reference documentation especially the chapter on jwt and implement it correctly. Why include a security framework if you not intend to use it? Downvoted because of poor research and not reading the spring security official documentation before asking on stack overflow.

Comment: @roberto The built-in filter that @Toerktumlare refers to is called `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` and can be configured to support validating signed JWTs. It is not necessary to write a custom filter. Again, please see [OAuth 2.0 Resource Server JWT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) in the reference docs.

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement a logic at the client side.
like when the oauth2 signin happens and you generate a jwt token make the client(here meaning browser or app) store the jwt and send it in subsequent requests to the backend until it expires and make a oauth2 signin after jwt expires.

this is how normal jwt token is maintained in the client side.
you can extract the jwt from request headers or in a cookie if you want in your filters

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the Greedy Cat's answer, I managed to find a solution as follows:

Use 2 endpoints, one of them to receive the `username` and `password` data and other to receive the `google access token`.

For both of them, I return the jwtToken for the api calls to these two endpoints.

Check out this cool tutorial that explains this very well at this link: [JWT and Social Authentication using Spring Boot](https://medium.com/javarevisited/jwt-and-social-authentication-using-spring-boot-90e4faaa9204)

Comment: the linked blogpost contains bad practices when it comes to implementation of authentication using JWTs and should be removed. Spring has full built in support for handling JWTs and how to implement it is declared in the Spring Security reference documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture the blog post writes custom security which is once again, bad practice.

Comment: okey thanks for you comment i will read the info and modify my code